# Simple regex pattern to match any .py files in specific directory

Tags: python, linux

Currently seeking for a solution to match `.py` files within directory `python36` and its subdirectories only.

Directory sample structure is next:

```
 - test.py
 - test2.py
 - python36/
   - script_1/
     - main.py
     - run.py
```

Following this example, i need to match files only within `python36` dir and all subdirs (obviously including `script_1/`).
I've tried `python36\/*` but it matches literally all files within directory, not only `.py`

Will appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you want to use the regular expression?

There are a few flavors of regex out there. Try this and if it doesn't help then supply more details:

```
^python36/.*\.py$
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use this regex: `dir_name/.*[.]py$` and change the dirname with you directory name

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it in python, you may want to use `os.walk()` to list files this way:

```
import os

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
    # keeps only the .py
    for filename in [fname for fname in filenames if fname.endswith(".py")]:
        print os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
```